# Windows API: Why does button hover effect gets jammed after a while?

Tags: c++, windows, button

Having recently started developing with the Windows API, I decided some interactivity was in order. So the plan was to use Owner Drawn buttons that would change background colour when the mouse enters their rectangular area, and changes back to the original colour when the mouse leaves.

I made 3 such buttons and sub-classed them with their own custom window procedure. Now because there is really no such thing as a `WM_MOUSEENTER` message I used the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and some mouse tracking to Fill the window with a certain colour. This basically means the rectangle gets filled every time the cursor moves inside the window.

I also used `WM_MOUSELEAVE` to fill the button when the mouse pointer moves outside the button's rectangle.

And this seems to work fine at first but after a while the rectangle filling will stop and the background will be stuck in either the hover colour or the default colour.

Here's the Code

```
#ifndef UWMENU_H_INCLUDED
#define UWMENU_H_INCLUDED
#endif // UWMENU_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK DBWndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
WNDPROC DBWndProcOld[3];

class UWMenu{
    public:
    //WINDOW PROCEDURE FOR NEWS BUTTON
    static LRESULT CALLBACK DBWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        HBRUSH BG_btnOne = CreateSolidBrush(NAV_BTN_DEF_CLR);
        HBRUSH BG_btnOneOver = CreateSolidBrush(NAV_BTN_OVER_CLR);

        int btnID = GetDlgCtrlID(hwnd);
        cout << btnID << "\n";

        switch(msg){
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:{

                cout << "Mouse is hovering over button\n";
                SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND));
                HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
                RECT rc;
                rc.left = 0;                            //Top left X coordinate of button's rectangular area
                rc.top = 0;                             //Top left Y coordinate of button's rectangular area
                rc.right = NAV_BTN_WIDTH;               //Bottom right X coordinate of button's rectangular area
                rc.bottom = NAV_BTN_HEIGHT;             //Bottom right Y coordinate of button's rectangular area

                printf("Repainting button background color\n");
                FillRect(hdc, &rc, BG_btnOneOver);
                SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255,255,255));
                SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);

                if(btnID == NBID_NEWS){DrawText(hdc, TXT_BN_NEWS, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);}
                if(btnID == NBID_TOOLS){DrawText(hdc, TXT_BN_TOOLS, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);}
                if(btnID == NBID_EDITOR){DrawText(hdc, TXT_BN_EDITORS, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);}
                ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
                tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
                tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
                tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
                TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            }
            break;

            case WM_MOUSELEAVE:{
                printf("You left me\n");
                SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));

                HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
                RECT rc;
                rc.left = 0;                                //Top left X coordinate of button's rectangular area
                rc.top = 0;                                 //Top left Y coordinate of button's rectangular area
                rc.right = NAV_BTN_WIDTH;                   //Bottom right X coordinate of button's rectangular area
                rc.bottom = NAV_BTN_HEIGHT;                 //Bottom right Y coordinate of button's rectangular area

                FillRect(hdc, &rc, BG_btnOne);
                SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255,255,255));
                SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
                if(btnID == NBID_NEWS){DrawText(hdc, TXT_BN_NEWS, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);}
                if(btnID == NBID_TOOLS){DrawText(hdc, TXT_BN_TOOLS, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);}
                if(btnID == NBID_EDITOR){DrawText(hdc, TXT_BN_EDITORS, -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);}
                ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
                tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                tme.dwFlags = TME_CANCEL;
                tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
                tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
                TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            }
            break;
        }
        return CallWindowProc(DBWndProcOld[btnID-200], hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};
```

The mouse_move messages are being processed as the output from `printf()` and `cout` are shown in debug mode when the mouse moves over the buttons.

Is there any way to fix this? Something to do with mouse tracking perhaps?

I think the problem is that the button is sort of getting spammed with the `FillRect()` while the pointer is inside its rectangle.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I did not found any suspicious lines in your code. However, from the description of the error, I would suggest that you check the count of gdi objects. Maybe there is a handle that does not get released.

Comment: How about `WM_MOUSEHOVER`? This looks like the message you are looking for, no?

Comment: The `WM_MOUSEHOVER` message does not actually do anything. Causes no change in the colour.

Comment: @Paraboloid87 Looking it Task Manager, there does seem to be some GDI leak. The number of GDI objects keeps ramping up and caps at 10,000

Comment: @Paraboloid87 Thanks for your help. The GDI leak is now fixed.

Comment: If you fixed the leak then edit the question or put answer to reflect it. It looks like you are forcing repaint every time the mouse moves while hovering, it should be fine though as long as you don't see flicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been solved now. It was due to a GDI leak. The problem was solved by deleting brushes that were being created repeatedly in a parent window procedure.